# Importing Lua files with weird behaviour?

Tags: lua, fivem

In my **fxmanifest.lua** file (simplified: handles imports and others)

I have:

```lua
server_scripts {
  ...
  'framework/server/classes/*.lua',
  ...
  'server/*.lua'
}
```

Which imports three classes:

1. **Items**
2. **Jobs**
3. **Player**
   [image]
   Then, proceeding to **server/base.lua** I create a new thread with these inside:

```lua
ZMan.Instantiate(1) -- From Player class
ZMan.AddItem("1", "2") -- From Items class
```

It works fine for **Instantiate** but not for **AddItem**
[image]

Comment: How did you define `ZMan` object?  Show your `player.lua`

Comment: https://github.com/iWanheda/zm-core/blob/main/framework/server/classes/player.lua

Comment: You have defined table `ZMan` which does not contain method `AddItem`.  If you want to inherit methods from some class you should make it explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following, what's the issue?

Comment: You have created a separate class `ZMan` instead of a subclass of the class `Items`.  So, you don't have access to methods of "Items"

Comment: But it works for other classes, why not Items? Also I actually think I'm not understanding can you send me the file which does so?

Comment: How would Lua know that you want to inherit methods from Items?  Where did you specify the link between Items and ZMan?  Please show this place in your code.